# How to speed up combination algorithm?

Tags: python, string, set, combinations, python-itertools

Code below finds minimum items of list `B` that forms string `A`. lets assume `A='hello world how are you doing'` and `B=['hello world how', 'hello are' ,'hello', 'hello are you doing']`. Then since items with index 0 and 3 contains all words of string `A`, the answer will be 2.

I converted all the strings to integer to speed up the algorithm, but since there are larger and complicated test cases I need more optimized algorithm. I wondering how to speed up this algorithm.

```
import itertools

A='hello world how are you doing'
B=['hello world how', 'hello are' ,'hello', 'hello are you doing']

d = {}
res_A = [d.setdefault(word, len(d)+1) for word in A.lower().split()]
mapping = dict(zip(A.split(), range(1, len(A) + 1)))

# find mappings of words in B
res_B = [[mapping[word] for word in s.split()] for s in B]

set_a = set(res_A)
solved = False

for L in range(0, len(res_B)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(res_B, L):
        s = set(item for sublist in subset for item in sublist)
        if set_a.issubset(s):
            print(f'{L}')
            solved = True
            break
    if solved: break
```

Comment: Your question is not completely clear. Does order matter? Can unrelated words appear in parts of the sentence (for example, would you still accept 'hello are you two doing'?)

Comment: The order does not matter. There are no unrelated words in list B.

Comment: This is a set covering problem. It is NP-hard, so brute-force isn't a good idea. A dynamic programming approach would likely be better.

Comment: I tried DP and brute force is the better than that.

Comment: What if there are duplicate words in either the "target" string or the individual list items?

Comment: It could be a duplicate words in both of them but it should cover all the words in A with minimum items of B

Answer (score 0):

I Had a logic mistake on remove_sub, no idea why it still worked

try cleaning the data and reducing as much items from b

```
import itertools as it
import time
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter, defaultdict as dd
import copy

A='hello world how are you doing'
B=['hello world how', 'hello are' ,'hello', 'hello are you doing']

d = {}
res_A = [d.setdefault(word, len(d)+1) for word in A.lower().split()
mapping = dict(zip(A.split(), range(1, len(A) + 1)))

# find mappings of words in B
res_B = [[mapping[word] for word in s.split()] for s in B]
set_a = set(res_A)

# my adding works on list of sets
for i in range(len(res_B)):
    res_B[i] = set(res_B[i])

# a is a list of numbers, b is a list of sets of numbers, we are trying to cover a using min items from b
a = np.random.randint(0,50,size = 30)
np_set_a  = set(a)
b = []
for i in range(200):
    size = np.random.randint(0,20)
    b.append(set(np.random.choice(a,size)))

# till here, created a,b for larger data test

def f1(set_a, b):
    solved = False
    for L in range(0, len(b)+1):
        for subset in it.combinations(b, L):
            s = set(item for sublist in subset for item in sublist)
            if set_a.issubset(s):
                print(f'{L}','**************f1')
                solved = True
                break
        if solved: break

def rare(b):
    c = Counter() #a dict where the key is a num and the value is how many times this num appears on all b sets
    items = dd(list) # dict where the key is num and value is list of index where this num exist in b
    for i in range(len(b)):
        c.update(b[i]) 
        for num in b[i]:
            items[num].append(i)

    rare = set()
    common = c.most_common() #return sorted list of tuples with a number and how many times it appear
    for i in range(1,len(common)-1): #take all the numbers that appear only once on b, these items will have to be on the final combination so you can remove them from b and their numbers from a because those numbers are covered
        if common[-i][1] ==1:
            rare.add(common[0])
            continue
        break

    rare_items = {} # a set of all index that have rare number in them
    for k in rare: 
        rare_items.update(items[k])

    values_from_rare_items = set() # a set of all the numbers in the items with the rare numbers
    for i in rare_items:
        values_from_rare_items.update(b[i])

    for i in reversed(sorted(rare_items)): #remove from b all the items with rare numbers, because they have to be on the final combination, you dont need to check them
        b.pop(i)
    return values_from_rare_items,b, len(rare_items)

#check sets on b, if 2 are equal remove 1, if 1 is a subset of the other, remove it 
def remove_sub(b):
    to_pop = set()
    t = copy.deepcopy(b)
    for i in range(len(b)):
        for j in range(len(t)):
            if i ==j:
                continue
            if b[i] == t[j]:
                to_pop.add(i)
                continue
            if b[i].issubset(t[j]):
                to_pop.add(i)
            if t[j].issubset(b[i]):
                to_pop.add(j)
    for i in reversed(sorted(to_pop)):
        b.pop(i)
    return b

def f2(set_a, b):
    b1 = remove_sub(b)
    values_from_rare_items,b2, num_rare_items = rare(b)
    a_without_rare = set_a-values_from_rare_items #remove from a all the number you added with the rare unique numbers, they are already covered
    

    solved = False
    for L in range(0, len(b2)+1):
        for subset in it.combinations(b2, L):
            s = set(item for sublist in subset for item in sublist)
            if a_without_rare.issubset(s):
                length = L+num_rare_items 
                print(f'{length}', "*********f2")
                solved = True
                break
        if solved: break


s = time.time()
f1(set_a,b)
print(time.time()-s,'********************f1')

s = time.time()
f2(set_a,b)
print(time.time()-s,'******************f2')


s = time.time()
f1(set_a,res_B)
print(time.time()-s,'********************f1')

s = time.time()
f2(set_a,res_B)
print(time.time()-s,'******************f2')
```

```
this is the out put

2 **************f1
0.16755199432373047 ********************f1 num_array

2 *********f2
0.09078240394592285 ******************f2 num_array

2 **************f1
0.0009989738464355469 ********************f1 your_data

2 *********f2
0.0009975433349609375 ******************f2 your_data
```

you can improve it more by taking all item that appear just few times, and treat them as if they appear once, in rare cases it will not be the real min number, but the time improvement is significant

Comment: Your code is kind of confusing for me. Would you please instead making random numbers use my strings and convert them into integers (same as my code) and then feed it to algorithm.

Comment: can there be words on B that don't appear on a? added a validation, any ways the idea is try to reduce B as much as possible, cause all combinations ~O(2^n) and any reduce in n is meaningful, and try to reduce a, as much as possible, to catch it in an early iteration